# Consuming PHP webservice with .Net C#, error with array

Tags: php, .net, arrays, web-services

I've a problem calling a PHP Web Service from .Net application.
This is the XML response and I think there is a problem with the *return* node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:infoprodottoResponse xmlns:ns1="http://wan3.edc.it">
        <result xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType=":[0]"></result>
        <error xsi:type="xsd:string">8u9lvDe3RBiGuXyL9lvM2tODlRMtcN77ya3S2LDEWEetBeRz/k4mXkK4hSqpgZOKilHYXgycj6Jtu8iBTfR1FQ==</error>
        <token xsi:type="xsd:string">5o58H00T96AWedhG1tnSc4xR+yXg7PQfQzXYVpri2AY=</token>
    </ns1:infoprodottoResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

In *result* node the *SOAP-ENC:arrayType* attribute hasn't declared the array type.
The array type must be declare if the *SOAP-ENC:arrayType* is present, isn't it?
It must be declared also if the array is empty?

Comment: Can you provide WSDL of the service?